# Confusion about domain adaptaion method: "Encoder" versus "prediction head"

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

In regard to this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.08105):

> Chen, D., Zhou, R., Pan, Y., & Liu, F. (2022). A Simple Baseline for Adversarial Domain Adaptation-based Unsupervised Flood Forecasting. arXiv preprint arXiv:2206.08105.

The authors describe two models. The first model is a 1D-CNN "encoder" with three layers. The second model is a "prediction head". It is also a 1D-CNN with three layers.

How to implement this?

For example, I'd start by creating two `Sequential()` models, each with three `Conv1D` layers and number of filters and kernel size as specified. Next step would be to train the encoder models on the source and target datasets. But what comes next?

For example:

```py
# Encoder model
encoder_model = Sequential()
encoder_model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',
  input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
encoder_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
encoder_model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
encoder_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
encoder_model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
encoder_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

```py
# Prediction head model
ph_model = Sequential()
ph_model.add(Conv1D(filters=36, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',
  input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
ph_model.add(Conv1D(filters=36, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
ph_model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3))
```

There is also a "residual connection" in the prediction head. But how to add that?

The article includes this diagram:
[image]

How would this look when programmed, for example, in keras?

Comment: You should probably ask this question directly to the authors of the article.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Please notice that the fact that a question has not received responses in some other SE site is **not** a reason for cross-posting it here; in any case, please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) (tl;dr: **no**, let alone the fact that the question is *not* on-topic here). Finally, in such cases you are generally expected to provide a *link* to the article yourself.

Comment: @desertnaut It's a programming question. How to implement this? In terms of sklearn, how would one go about combining two models in the fashion suggested by the article?

Comment: @desertnaut I've updated the questions so that it is different from the CV question. This is about programming. The CV question is about theory.

Comment: Not sure why you refer to scikit-learn while showing Keras code; still, while not a cross-post, the question "*what next? Train the second model on the second dataset?*" is not a *programming* one. In order to pose a programming question (*how to do it*) you need to know *what* to do, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @desertnaut I added some code for how I think it works. But really I have no idea. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!